# Remove a color transform?

Tags: actionscript-3

How do I remove a color transform? (If say, I want to revert back to the original color):

I tried null but this gives me a null error:

```
my-movieclip-name.transform.colorTransform = null;
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Just reset the color transform by creating a new instance of it:

```
myTransform = new ColorTransform();
```

Comment: Yep. By default, every `DisplayObject` has a `colorTransform` of: `(redMultiplier=1, greenMultiplier=1, blueMultiplier=1, alphaMultiplier=1, redOffset=0, greenOffset=0, blueOffset=0, alphaOffset=0)`. There's no removing it, only resetting.

Answer (score 3):

instead of recreating a `ColorTransform` object you can reset the current one as follows:

```
myTransform.redMultiplier = 1;

myTransform.greenMultiplier = 1;

myTransform.blueMultiplier = 1;

myTransform.redOffset = 0;

myTransform.greenOffset = 0;

myTransform.blueOffset = 0;
```